# Is it grammatically correct to say "the smartest thing I have done is stop junk food"?

Tags: difference, bare-infinitives

Could you tell me if it's correct and natural to say the following?

> The smartest thing I have done is **stop** eating junk food.

If it's not, thend would it be more natural if I said this way?

> The smartest thing I have done is **stoping** eating junk food.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct form is:
"The smartest thing I have done is to stop eating junk food".

This is the infinitive form "to stop" used as a noun, also known as a gerund.

As an aside, "stopping" is the correct spelling of *that* word.